# Detect First Time User

Tags: objective-c, xcode, cocoa

How can I detect if the user has just downloaded the application and opened it for the first time? IS this a NSUserDefaults? I want to be able to show a welcome screen only the first time my application is run.

Thanks

Comment: Yap you can save any value in NSUserDefaults and in appDelegate check wether your NSUserDefault having that value or not. If not then show welcome screen.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

check for a bool in NSUserDefaults and if it is not set do whatever you want and save a YES-bool back to NSUserDefaults. If you show an alert you probably should put the `setBool:forKey:` in the delegate method which is called after you have dismissed the alert.

```
if (![[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] boolForKey:@"wasLaunchedBefore"]) {
    NSLog(@"First launch");
    [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults] setBool:YES forKey:@"wasLaunchedBefore"];
}
```

Answer (score 2):

You can use the NSUSerDefaults.By this when the user opened app check whether there is any values in your user defaults for a key.If it is not then that is first time.After this check you have to update the value for the key which you have checked previously.

Answer (score 0):

You can check if flag is set in NSPreferences or check if file exists in app's file (file that you create after the first launch).

Answer (score 0):

You need to set in your application if opened first time then show that stuff which you want to show first time. There is no any other way to find out that user downloaded your application and he run it or not. On run process you need to set it inside your application.

Answer (score 0):

If you use NSUserDefaults then user can reinstall your application. And application will think thank user use it for first time again. But after updating application remembers that the user has already launched it.

I can't understand from your question if it is appropriate for you but the most of applications work this way